# gradle remove main source set

Tags: gradle, source-sets

```
src
  main/java
  test/java
```

The test does not depend on main for compiling. Tying to compile and run test on another library replacing main.

```
sourceSets {
   remove main
}

gradle test
```

It will always compile the main source set.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `sourceSets.remove(sourceSets.main)`

as `sourcesets {}` delegates to  https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/SourceSetContainer.html